# Replace only one instance of a duplicate in a string. Python

Tags: python, string

Part of my program generates a string, e.g. `D D` or `N D` etc. I want to replace the first instance of a certain character with a correlating character (specified elsewhere in the code).
So if the string is `D D` I want to be able to get `0 D`

I tried using the `.replace()` function, but that gives me `0 0` as it replaces all instances of that character.

Any tips on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `str.replace` function takes a 3rd count argument:

```
>>> 'D D'.replace('D', '0', 1)
'0 D'
```

in other words, replace only 1 D.

Comment: oh, that's painfully obvious. Feeling rather stupid now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No worries... believe me, I've been there ;).